# Is it possible for git to ignore everything git-related and simply add the complete working tree?

Tags: backup, git

So I was thinking of switching my personal data backup strategy from rsync to git. For this, I would like to simply initialize my personal folder as a repository, and regular backups would simply be new commits. However, all my 'real' git repositories (of software projects etc) are inside my personal folder, so git warns me of embedded git repositories and asks me to add a submodule instead (even when using `--force`). I would like to tell my top repository to treat everything underneath it simply as files and add as is, with no interpretation (ideally even ignoring all `.gitignore` files in subdirectories<sup>1</sup>). Basically, I want to make sure that the content of this top repository is identical with my complete user folder. Is this possible? Is this a bad idea?

[1] Not "ignore" as in "not track the file itself" of course, but meta-ignore as in "do not interpret it as a file relevant for the git process"

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. Git performance degrades with the number of files and commits; at some point your backup will be unusable. You'll always carry around everything, or you have to prune files in a very weird way. Not even mentioning large files (for which LFS exists, but it adds complexity). Is there any particular reason you need Git and not an actual backup solution (Borg backup comes to mind).

Comment: Well, my reason was mostly because git is familiar, easy to use and so popular that it'll always be available. But I'll give borg a look, thanks!